# Связать методы и поля классов

Tags: java, netbeans

Мне необходимо смоделировать игровые автоматы с магнитными лентами,на которых хранится только баланс,номер и ничего больше.Терминалом,через который можно пополнять баланс и обменивать заработанные очки на призы. А также играми,где эти очки зарабатываются.

Так вот,суть вопроса в следующем:как связать между собой классы.То есть чтобы пополнять баланс можно было только через терминал.Но при этом и в играх и терминале используются поля магнитных карт,которые являются отдельным классом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Вариант №1

Я бы предложил создать аннотацию. Например, `Replenishable`

```java
package com.example;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * Аннотация, определяющая, что классу разрешено пополнение
 */
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Replenishable { }
```

Далее пометил бы этой аннотацией класс `Terminal`, которому разрешено пополнение:

```java
@Replenishable 
public class Terminal {
   public Map.Entry<Boolean, String> replenish(String accountNumber, BigDecimal amount) {
   //some logic
   }
}
```

И в методе-обработчике проверил, что оплату осуществлял класс, который соответствующим образом аннотирован:

```java
Replenishable isReplenishable = terminalObject.getClass().getAnnotation(Replenishable.class);
if (Objects.nonNull(isReplenishable)) {
    //receive payment
} else {
   throw new RuntimeException("Пополнение счёта произведено из неавторизованного источника");
}
```

В итоге, когда мы хотим добавить какому-то классу возможность пополнения, то мы просто аннотируем его (терминалы, игры и т.д.).

### Вариант №2

Использовать интерфейсы:

1. Создадим интерфейс `Replenishable`
2. Имплементируем его в `Terminal` и `Game`
3. Внутри обработчика проверим, что объект реализует `Replenishable`:

```java
public static boolean isReplenishable(Class<?> clazz) {
   Class<?>[] interfaces = clazz.getInterfaces();
   return Arrays.asList(interfaces).contains(Replenishable.class);
}
```

### Вариант №3

Использовать наследование:

1. Создать абстрактный класс `Replenishable`
2. Наследовать от него `Terminal` и `Game`
3. При помощи Reflection Api проверить, что кто-то из цепочки родителей является `Replenishable`.

```java
public static boolean isReplenishable(Class<?> clazz) {
    boolean contains = false;
    do {
        contains = clazz.isAssignableFrom(Replenishable.class);

        Class<?> superClass = clazz.getSuperclass();
        if (superClass == null) {
            break;
        }

        clazz = superClass;
    } while (!contains || !"java.lang.Object".equals(clazz.getCanonicalName()));

    return contains;
}
```